# How to use Stanford CoreNLP POS-tags to retrieve synsets from WordNet?

Tags: java, stanford-nlp, wordnet, pos-tagger

I'm working with Java in Eclipse, & Stanford CoreNLP. I wanna know how to use the POS tags generated by Stanford CoreNLP, to retrieve the synsets of tagged words from WordNet. (I tokenized the sentence before POS-tagging)

Since WordNet has POS-tagged synsets, I'm assuming it can be done. I looked up a few tutorials as well, but there's nothing much helpful.

Comment: First, I want to filter out just the nouns, verbs, & adjectives from all the tagged words, and then use those for the above mentioned purpose.

Comment: So, I kinda resolved it. Since WN uses Penn Treebank notation, I wrote a method for getting synsets for each relevant tag.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by WN using Penn Treebank notation; but as per the other thread as well, my recommendation would be implement a variant of the Lesk algorithm, or else see if the most common sense baseline works well enough to be useful.

Answer (score 0):

the following code gets all synsets of searchWord+POS tag, then from them prints their glosses. you can change POS.NOUN to seach other forms of the searchword:

```
public int stackoverflow(String searchWord) throws IOException {
        String s = null;
        IDictionary dict = dicitionaryFactory();
        try {

            IIndexWord idxWord = dict.getIndexWord(searchWord, POS.NOUN);
            for (int i = 0; i < idxWord.getWordIDs().size(); i++) {
            IWordID wordID = idxWord.getWordIDs().get(i); // ist meaning
            edu.mit.jwi.item.IWord word = dict.getWord(wordID);
            edu.mit.jwi.item.ISynset synset = word.getSynset();
            List<edu.mit.jwi.item.IWord> words;
            System.out.println(synset.getGloss());

            }
            return -1;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return -2;
        }
    }
```